# d3-cloud - How to scale weight of words?

Tags: javascript, browserify, d3-cloud

I have an API that returns a JSON like this:

```
{
   "\u062a\u0626\u0627\u062a\u0631":60.83632993941593,
   "\u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc\u06af\u0631":51.61183191236724,
   "\u0647\u0646\u0631\u0645\u0646\u062f":33.14581325884296,
   "\u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634":30.25039526965043,
   ...
}
```

These are persian letters, that the browser shows fine:

[image]

Now I want to create a word cloud of this JSON file using [d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) library.

This is the script I wrote for it:

```
let draw_wordcloud = function (url) {
    let words_list = []
    fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (data) {
            for (let key in data) {
                words_list.push({
                    text: key,
                    size: data[key]
                })
            }
        })
    let draw = function (words) {
        d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", layout.size()[0])
            .attr("height", layout.size()[1])
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + layout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + layout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(words)
            .enter().append("text")
            .style("font-size", function (d) {
                return d.size + "px";
            })
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.text;
            })

    }

    list_to_print = [
        "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
        "than", "this"
    ].map(function (d) {
        return {
            text: d,
            size: 10 + Math.random() * 90
        };
    })

    console.log(list_to_print)
    console.log(words_list)
    let layout = cloud()
        .size([500, 500])
        .words(list_to_print)
        .padding(1)
        .rotate(0)
        .font("Impact")
        .fontSize(function (d) {
            return d.size;
        })
        .on("end", draw)

    layout.start()
}

draw_wordcloud('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amirashabani/karamuzi/master/root.json')
```

When I use the [word list provided in the example of the library](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/browserify.js#L6) things work fine:

[image]

But when I use the word list I created from the JSON file, no word cloud is shown:

[image]

I think the problem is with the `size` of objects in my JSON file that `d3-cloud` can't create the word cloud, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried rounding the size, using `Math.round`, but it didn't work. How can I fix this?

I couldn't make a working snippet, because the *browserified* version of my script is 19K lines, so I posted the script itself.

As per [@schu34's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010339/d3-cloud-how-to-scale-weight-of-words?noredirect=1#comment104268711_59010339) I changed it to see if this library has a problem with non-English letters, so I gave it this:

```
let another_list = [
    { text: 'تئاتر', size: 12.911860924743902 },
    { text: 'بازیگر', size: 63.482378561566065 },
    { text: 'هنرمند', size: 95.11044438217024 },
    { text: 'نمایش', size: 29.909944419309827 },
    { text: 'سینما', size: 72.11666142061274 },
    { text: 'تئاتربازها', size: 80.18256640600696 },
    { text: 'تلویزیون', size: 63.59191944570398 }
]
```

And we can see that this library shows Persian letters just fine:

[image]

The numbers in this example are those generated by this part of the example provided by the library (modified to show Persian letters):

```
another_list = [
    "تئاتر", "بازیگر", "هنرمند", "نمایش", "سینما", "تئاتربازها", "تلویزیون"
].map(function (d) {
    return {
        text: d,
        size: 10 + Math.random() * 90
    };
})
```

So I don't think the problem is with the library.

Comment: just a stab in the dark, but I wonder if d3 is just having trouble with the non-English characters?

Comment: @schu34 I don't think that's the problem. Updated my question.